# Struct with array of variable size

Tags: c, dynamic, struct

I want to have a struct which contains arrays of variable size. I want to be able to initialize `p` lists with different sizes `n=[2,4,7]`.

Since I am new to C, this is a little bit tricky for me. I tried the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    double **plist;
} ParticleList;

void sendPar(ParticleList *pl, int *n, int np){
    pl -> plist = malloc(sizeof(double*) * np);
    for(int p=0; p<np; p++){
        pl->plist[p] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n[p]);
    }

    for(int p=0; p<np; p++){
        for(int k=0; k<n[p]; k++){
            pl->plist[p][k] = k+1;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    ParticleList pl;
    int np = 3;
    int n[np];
    n[0] = 2;
    n[1] = 4;
    n[2] = 7;

    sendPar(&pl, n, np);

    // Listsizes
    for(int p=0; p<np; p++){
        printf("Size of List %d is %lu\n", p, sizeof(pl.plist[p]));
    }
}
```

When I try this, all my lists `plist[]` have the same size. What am I doing wrong?

The output is

```
Size of List 0 is 8
Size of List 1 is 8
Size of List 2 is 8
```

But I would expect something like

```
Size of List 0 is 16
Size of List 1 is 32
Size of List 2 is 56
```

Comment: A pointer is not an array. Use a flexible array member.

Comment: @Olaf I know that a pointer is not an array. Maybe I did something wrong in the code above. Can you give me a hint how I can make it work?

Comment: `int n[p] = {2,4,7};` : VLA can't have initializer.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/3hxVQd)

Comment: @Samuel, very confusing that using `pList` as a variable name `myList pList;` and as a structure name `double *pList;` then you need to write `pList->pList ...` to manage arrays of double.

Comment: Read more about C, notably about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You probably have a good use case for these.

Comment: "I know that a pointer is not an array" - So why don't you use an array then? I gave you a clear hint.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Your example is very clear and I understand it so far. But why do we need `sizeof(double*)` in `malloc()` and not `sizeof(double)`?. And how can I fill my lists with numbers? Like `pList->pLst[k] = 42`?

Comment: @Olaf I updated my question. Some things are now clearer. But I am still not sure, why my lists appear the have the same size.

Comment: `double **` is pointer to `double*` So It need `sizeof(double*)`.  [sample of fill numbers](http://ideone.com/3hxVQd)

Comment: `sizeof(pl.plist[p])` : type of `pl.plist[p]` is `double*`. So, `sizeof(pl.plist[p])` is pointer size, not contents size.

Comment: There is a major missconception about what arrays in C are and how the `sizeof` operator works.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How can I determine the size of the list?

Comment: There is no way to know the size of its contents from the pointer itself. There are methods such as putting sentinel, but in this case it is better to keep it in the structure itself.

Comment: Source code doesn't compile... Where come from `numprocs` and `s->numprocs` ?

Comment: @J.Piquard Now it compiles. Sorry. I tried to simplify the code as much as possible and forgot to change some variables.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can I also do `pl -> plist = malloc(sizeof(ParticleList) * np);`?

Comment: It's wrong. `ParticleList` isn't The type of element. （However, if the element type size and `ParticleList` size are  same size, the program will work.）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the size of allocated arrays of double and maintain the 2D array access algorithm, you can modify the `ParticleList` structure as follow:

**Step 1** - add a array of int to store individual size

```
typedef struct{
    int *pSize;
    double **plist;
} ParticleList;
```

**Step 2** - during the allocation in `sendPar()` function, allocate and initialize the `pSize` array

```
void sendPar(ParticleList *pl, int *n, int np){
    pl->plist = malloc(sizeof(double*) * np);
    pl->pSize = malloc(sizeof(int) * np); // allocate the pSize array
    for (int p=0; p<np; p++){
        pl->pSize[p] = n[p]; // initialize the pSize Arry
        pl->plist[p] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n[p]);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Step 3** - from `main` to manage each array of double with its own size

```
// Listsizes
for(int p=0; p<np; p++){
    printf("Size of List %d is %lu\n", p, (pl.pSize[p]*sizeof(double))));
}
```